# Why am I getting two task bar icons?

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell, remote-desktop

I have written a WinForms application to automatically log me in to remote sessions using stored credentials. Here's my code:

```
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(String.Format("cmdkey /generic:\"{0}\" /user:\"{1}\" /pass:\"{2}\" \n", selectedProject.IpAddress, selectedProject.UserName, selectedProject.Password));
        builder.Append(String.Format("mstsc /v:\"{0}\"", selectedProject.IpAddress));
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(builder.ToString());

        pipeline.Invoke();
        runSpace.Close();
```

It works fine apart from, when it launches the RDP session, it puts a second icon in my task bar (not an RDP icon - my app icon). The icon persists even after I close the RDP session. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

The Runspace invocation creates a separate thread and thus an additional icon in the task bar.

Comment: It persists even after the runSpace.Close() command. Is there a better way to terminate this?

Comment: Include     runspace.Dispose();
 
          GC.Collect();

Comment: On re-compiling, this is again keeping the task bar icon alive. Any other ideas welcome.